# How move polygons along the normals with Animation nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

Im new in animation nodes. And maybe it is very easy question but I cant find solution by myself. I`m trying to make transformation animation and I handled with moving vertices on normals but as I understand polygons have a different approach.

[image: polygons move only in world coordinates]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the “**Polygon Info**” node to access each node's normal and then  pass it through a “**Translation Matrix**” into the ”“**Transform Polygon**” node.

The *Polygon Info*'s center output can also be used in calculations regarding the translation distance, e.g. the distance to an Empty or the angle from the torus' center.

BTW: Animation Nodes includes a “**Transform Individual Polygons**” template which adds the underlying node setup of looping over all polygons and outputting the mesh. You then just need to set up the transformation matrix.

[image: Node setup for polygons translated along their normals]